# VBA Auto Vlookup That works with variable range in multiple different sheets, Can it be done?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to make The Vlookup Formula to work with multiple Excel Files (each File has a different columns arrangement),  the first row in all those Files has multiple IDs that represent a certain object.

example (Words Translation):

The Sheet is empty, only the top row has IDs, And each ID is in a separate Column.

Let's say there is a Column with ID 10 And another Column with the ID 20 (Columns arrangement change with each file), And The Goal is to Vlookup what's in The Column that Contains The ID 10 and go to a Table array in another Sheet Called Transwords and look it up in both Columns A And B and get Translated word from The Second Column (which will be B in this case), then return the result in the first Sheet under the column that contains the ID 20.

I have tried to do it myself but it didn't work because every excel file has different columns arrangement and I am trying to make the vlookup search columns with certain IDs , the columns could be A And E or D and F (it's the ID that matters) .. etc

I asked a question earlier and got some help from the good people in here, but I didn't explain my problem well, they did help but they weren't aware of what I am trying to do.

so my question is, Can it be done? Or I am trying to do something Impossible!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use VLOOKUPS nested, so your first one will use MATCH in the column number part

Answer (score 0):

I have my data set up to simulate yours.

I have my col x table in $G$3:$L$7 (im just using 1 to 5 as the left hand column for the VLOOKUP, in the example, looking for 3). and my translation table, the 2nd bit in $M$10:$N$13.

Unfortunately I cant upload pictures at work.

The formula is

`=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(3,$G$3:$L$7,MATCH("col 2",$G$2:$L$2,0)),$M$10:$N$13,2,0)`